# Excel formula to find amount of columns filled

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, vba

I hope everyone is having a great day. I have an excel file where the employees ID number is in column A. Then I have 4 other columns that tell me if an employee filled out data for Degree, Work Experience, Experience Level and Languages known. The employee may appear more than once therefore creating several lines for the same employee.

I need to know of a formula that will detect how many of the lines the employee has filled in. The trick here is for example if an employee has already filled in the four columns in any one of the rows to just appear as complete.

I tied using an IF formula but its not working for me.

Comment: please provide a sample data set and what you expect. give a clear example. you can provide a link to your screenshot of the data in the comments and we will upload it to the question.

Comment: Add a helper column (Let's say B) and put the formula in B2 `=CountA(C2:F2)`. I am assuming that the data is from Col C to F. Change as applicable. Now check which cell in Col B has a value of `4` against a particular employee. Hope I have understood your query.

Comment: [link](http://1drv.ms/1G3HVr2) here it is...

Comment: So my guess was right. :D Follow what is mentioned in my comment above and see if that is what you want? You can also change the formula to `=If(CountA(C2:F2)=4,"Complete","")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for `VBA`. As I suggested in my comments above, add a helper column (**Let's say in B**) and put the formula mentioned below in cell `B2` and pull it down.

```
=IF(COUNTA(C2:F2)=4,"Complete","")
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the `UsedRange` property.

E.g.,

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question :)